# Prevent a form from freezing

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on my project and automatically sending email, but my form is affected and freezes until the process was finished. How to work on it without freezing current window? I'm working on VB.Net.

Comment: I found a video on youtube about backgroundworker and starting to work on it. I hope it solves my problem.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv4FdoaUMQE

Comment: There are plenty of resources better than youtube - MSDN for instance, and also gobs of questions here.  Most youtube videos reduce it to a magic spell (with bad music) - click here; type this; click here; type this.  You end up not knowing anything at all about what it does, why some thing are this or that or anything else that it is essential for you to know about the tech you are working with.

Comment: That YouTube video also provides some **very bad advice**. Do not consider setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCall = False`. This is for debugging only.

Comment: I found the way!

Comment: BackgroundWorker is the solution.

Comment: I did not used that CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCall = False, and works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Your send e-mail code is running synchronously with the UI thread.  You will need to run that code on a separate thread in order to maintain UI responsiveness.

Take a look at the following to get you started:

[Safe, Simple Multithreading in Windows Forms, Part 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx)

[Multithreading in Windows Forms Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229730(v=vs.110).aspx)

The first link is quite old but it shows how to accomplish what you're attempting using the Thread class.  If you don't care about synchronizing with your form and setting properties on controls, then this will do what you want.  However, I would prefer the second link...

The second link uses the BackgroundWorker.  This is the prefered method, at least for me.  You can fire-and-forget if you don't care about being notified of the process (sending e-mail in this case) completing.  However, with this class you can also work directly with the form and it's controls from the BackgroundWorker's RunWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: Currently looking at it sir.

Comment: Anyone care to explain how my answer was not useful?

Comment: I didn't downvote however it could be for a few reasons. 1. Some people like to see the world burn. 2. It's a poor question and by answering you're keeping the question alive 3. You've not really provided any context from the links in your answer. Links can die and if they do the content dies with them.

Comment: Points taken, thanks Bugs!  I'm just getting back into answering questions on SO after a long time away.

Comment: @ScottPage not a problem.